# List<myObject> mismatch in save method

Tags: java, spring

I wrote a save method that will accept the list of objects from UI side. I was getting bad request error (400) when i tried to send a field name myObjects from UI.

I my product bean myObjects is a type of

```
List<myObject> myObjects ;
```

from UI i am sending myObjects in below form-

```
myObjects: Array[1]
      0: Object
         critical: "TRUE"
         id: "12"
         Envelope: "TRUE"
         pageCount: "12"
         paperStock: "ss"
         quantity: "12"
         type: "PRODUCT"
  __proto__: Object
   length: 1
```

My save method-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config/product", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> saveProduct(@RequestBody final Product product)
{
    something---
    ResponseEntity<String> returnValue;
    returnValue = productService.saveProduct(product);   
}
```

I was getting an ajax error in chrome console itself. Request is not itself going to my controller.

```
POST http://localhost:8000/myportal/app/config/product 400 (Bad Request)
```

What is wrong in that? any suggestion?

Comment: can you show your console log please ??

Comment: and your controller method please??

Comment: When am excluding this field while saving. then save method works fine for me. I dont know what i did wrong

Comment: I need more information.. I will have to see your product model with its attributes and annotations